# Variance of a random sum, with a random variable as upper limit

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, variance

How did they get this result starting in ($\star$)?

Define:
$X_0 := 1, X_{n+1} = \sum_{i=1}^{X_n} Y_i$
with
$Y_i$ iid for all $i = 1,2,\ldots$, and $\mathbb{E}(Y_i) = \mu, \operatorname{Var}(Y_i) = \sigma^2$.
We found that $\mathbb{E}(X_n) = \mu^{n}$.

We want to find the variance of $X_{n+1}$.

$$\operatorname{Var}(X_{n+1})= \mathbb{E}(\operatorname{Var}(X_n \mid X_{n+1}) + \operatorname{Var}(\mathbb{E}(X_{n}\mid X_{n+1}) \\ = \sigma^2 \mu^{n-1} + \mu^2 \operatorname{Var}(X_{n-1})$$

Since $\operatorname{Var}(X_0) = 0$ and $\operatorname{Var}(X_1) = \sigma^2$, we obtain:
$$\operatorname{Var}(X_n) = \sigma^2 (\mu^{n-1} + \mu^n + \cdots +\mu^{2n-2}) \qquad  (\star)$$

Comment: I tried doing this:  
$$\mathrm{Var}(X_{n+1}) - \mathrm{Var}(X_{n-1}) = \sigma^2 \mu^{n-1} + (\mu^2 - 1)\mathrm{Var}(X_{n-1})$$  
and then forming more equations with difference indexes, then summing to get  
$$\mathrm{Var}(X_n) - \mathrm{Var}(X_1) = (\mu^2 -1)(\mathrm{Var}(X_1) + \ldots + \mathrm{Var}(X_{n-1})) + \sigma^2 (\mu + \mu^2 + \ldots + \mu^{n-1})$$  which doesn't seem to help.

Comment: You have $ \operatorname{E}(\operatorname{Var}(X_n \mid X_{n+1}) + \operatorname{Var}(\operatorname{E}(X_n\mid X_{n+1}) $ where you need $$ \operatorname{E}(\operatorname{Var}(X_{n+1} \mid X_n) + \operatorname{Var}(\operatorname{E}(X_{n+1} \mid X_n).$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula before $(\star)$ is incorrect. It should read:
$$
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}(X_{n})&= \mathbb{E}(\operatorname{Var}(X_n \mid X_{n-1})) + \operatorname{Var}(\mathbb{E}(X_n \mid X_{n-1})) \\ 
&= \sigma^2 \mu^{n-1} + \mu^2 \operatorname{Var}(X_{n-1})
\end{align}
$$
You should be able to get to $(\star)$ from here.

Comment: I'm not sure how to get to $(\star)$. Is it just by iteratively substituting it in or can we solve it with other methods?

Comment: @Twenty-sixcolours You can iteratively substitute. Or use induction:  $(\star)$ holds when $n=1$, so now assume it holds for $n=k$ and show that it then holds for $n=k+1$.